# Copy all Files in a List to a Unique Directory

Tags: list, shell, text, emacs

I am trying to take a text file that contains a list of files and copy them all to a directory. Within this directory, they will have unique directory names. An example of text file the structure can be seen below:

```
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000003/s01_2011_11_01/a_.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000003/s01_2011_11_01/a_1.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000003/s02_2011_11_11/a_.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000003/s02_2011_11_11/a_1.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s01_2009_02_13/a_.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s02_2010_10_02/a_.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s03_2010_10_02/a_.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s04_2010_10_03/a_.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s04_2010_10_03/a_1.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s04_2010_10_03/a_2.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s04_2010_10_03/a_3.edf
/data/isip/data/tuh_eeg/v0.6.0/edf/001/00000005/s04_2010_10_03/a_4.edf
```

I need a shell command or an EMACS macro to go through this list and copy them all to unique directories within the current working directory. The unique directory will depend on the file; for example, for the first two files, the directory would be

```
/001/00000003/s01_2011_11_01/
```

I have tried doing this using an EMACS macro, but I was not able to get it to work. A shell command or EMACs macro would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as:

```
cat list | sed "s/^.*edf\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)$/mkdir -p root_dir\/\1 \&\& cp \0 root_dir\/\1\/\2/" | sh
```

If on OSX - install gnu-sed and use gsed instead of sed. Run command without | sh to see what it'll do. Make sure to tweak root_dir, of course.